# karate: how to validate complex Api responses using karate?

Tags: karate

i have two different responses as below, where i want to match only title of the type "Top-Tier Category" in response1 with  "category_name" of the response2. here i don't want to match "type": "Top-Tier Top-List" in response1.

Note : "title" in response1 is equal to "category_name" in response2

Please let me know how to do this validations in karate. thanks in advance

Comment: given comments for  stackoverflow.com/a/56149489/143475

Comment: accepted stackoverflow.com/a/56149489/143475

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have read all the documentation ? This should be straightforward, for example:

```
* def response = { title: 'foo' }
* def response1 = response
# make second request
* def response = { category_name: 'foo' }
* match response.category_name == response1.title
```

If the above is not clear, I strongly advise you consider using other tools that may be simpler for you.

Comment: i understood ur logic..... how to do same with different type and tiles names? 
for example response1 has multiple titles for different type like {
    "data": { "bookgroups": [{"type": "Category","title": "lifestyle","position":69, "allowsorting": 1},{ "type": "List","title": "Popular", "position": 0, "allowsorting": 0},{"type": "Category","title": "fantasy", "position": 70,"allowsorting": 1}]}
 Here i want to compare only title of the type "category" with another response(response 2) which has titles of only  "Category" type

Comment: response1  = [{ a: 'abc', b: 'x' }, { a: 'efg', b: 'y' }]

response2 = [{ c: 'abc', d: 'z' }, { e: 'efg', f: 'z' }] here i wants to match value 'abc' in response1 with the value 'abc' in responce2